# How to use the name of a dataframe to assign an id inside a R function?

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

I am struggling with a problem since a few days now. I am trying to combine various dataframes together.  The dataframes are currently in my environment.  In order to group them together, I want to understand to what dataframe in the environemnt each record is refering to.

There is a puzzeling element.  when I am running the substitute function outside the function I am writing, everything runs smoothly.  However, when I am inserting the substitute in the function I am writing, nothing works.

```r
# the list of dataframe I want to group together is extracted from the environment... 
# everything is ok for now. I get a nice list.
df_list <- mget(ls(pattern= "^tmls"))

# now I want to (1) select various fields in the dataframe and (2)  
# assign the name of each elements to the records in order to perform  
# further groupings when the list will be combined in a single table.

#solution 1 (the x is returned instead of the dataframe name)
df_listx <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {
  x <- x %>%  
    select(created_at, text, retweet_count, favorite_count, lang, reply_count) %>%  
    mutate(nom = deparse(substitute(x)))
})

#solution 2 (nothing is returned --> the x dataframe however gets the desired result.)
library(rlang)
nom_dataframe2 <- function(x) { 
 y <<- deparse(substitute(x)) 
 z <<- match.call() 
 # I also tried "match.call" inorder to assign the name of the dataframe... with no effect
 {{x}} := x %>% mutate(nom = y)  
 return(x)
 }
```

I am puzzeled here however. When I am running the deparse / substitute function, everything works great outside the function.  WHen I run it inside the function, it is another story.  Instead of getting the name of the dataframe, I get the nameof the variable (x).  I tried various solutions on Stackoverflow, but none seemed to work so far.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Map` across the values and names combined?

```r
df_listx <- Map(function(x, nm) {
  x <- x %>%  
    select(created_at, text, retweet_count, favorite_count, lang, reply_count) %>%  
    mutate(nom = nm)
}, df_list, names(df_list))
```

Otherwise, `substitute(deparse(..))` is only going to be able to peek at what the next-level (parent call) used for the object name.

Comment: This is simple, it makes sense and I learned something tonight. Thanks a lot, this was much helpful! (I had to add a comma after the bracket for the solution to fully work, otherwise I was getting an error. )  But I have a smile now, I can move ahead with my project !

Comment: Yup, typo, glad you were able to fix it.